# Confluent S3 sink connector with Strimzi Kafka Connect on EKS: Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception with PartitionerConfig error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, strimzi

I got a problem for a weeks of my deployment the Strimzi Kafka Connect with Confluent S3 sink connector plugins

I work with instruction from Strimzi itself to create the Kafka Connect Cluster pods on EKS

After create the connector task, I got this error around a PartitionerConfig

```
 (io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.PartitionerConfig) [task-thread-abc-dp-test-sink-connector-0]
2023-05-31 08:43:28,563 ERROR [abc-dp-test-sink-connector|task-0] WorkerSinkTask{id=abc-dp-test-sink-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask) [task-thread-abc-dp-test-sink-connector-0]
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector.<init>(io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnectorConfig, java.lang.String)
        at io.confluent.connect.storage.StorageFactory.createStorage(StorageFactory.java:55)
        at io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkTask.start(S3SinkTask.java:108)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:312)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:186)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:243)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector.<init>(io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnectorConfig, java.lang.String)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2151)
        at io.confluent.connect.storage.StorageFactory.createStorage(StorageFactory.java:49)
        ... 9 more
```

Here's my docker files to construct the image to include Confluent S3 Sink connector plugins

Dockerfile

```
FROM quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.31.1-kafka-3.1.0-amd64
USER root:root
RUN mkdir -p /opt/kafka/plugins/confluentinc-connect-transforms-1.4.3
RUN mkdir -p /opt/kafka/plugins/confluentinc-kafka-connect-avro-converter-7.2.2
RUN mkdir -p /opt/kafka/plugins/confluentinc-kafka-connect-protobuf-converter-7.2.2
RUN mkdir -p /opt/kafka/plugins/confluentinc-kafka-connect-s3-10.5.0-3
COPY ./confluentinc-connect-transforms-1.4.3/* /opt/kafka/plugins/confluentinc-connect-transforms-1.4.3
COPY ./confluentinc-kafka-connect-avro-converter-7.2.2/* /opt/kafka/plugins/confluentinc-kafka-connect-avro-converter-7.2.2
COPY ./confluentinc-kafka-connect-protobuf-converter-7.2.2/* /opt/kafka/plugins/confluentinc-kafka-connect-protobuf-converter-7.2.2
COPY ./confluentinc-kafka-connect-s3-10.5.0-3/* /opt/kafka/plugins/confluentinc-kafka-connect-s3-10.5.0-3
USER 1001
```

and this is a part of yaml file to create Connect Cluster with Strimzi Cluster Operator

```
...
spec:
    version: 3.1.0
    replicas: 2
    image: s3-sink-image-repo:latest
    bootstrapServers: bootstrap_server1:9094,bootstrap_server2:9094
    config:
        group.id: connect-cluster
        offset.storage.topic: connect-cluster-offsets-v1
        config.storage.topic: connect-cluster-configs-v1
        status.storage.topic: connect-cluster-status-v1
        key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
        value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
        key.converter.schemas.enable: true
        value.converter.schemas.enable: true
        config.storage.replication.factor: 2
        offset.storage.replication.factor: 2
        status.storage.replication.factor: 2
...
```

When I create the connector with class io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector

```
...
spec:
  class: io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector
  tasksMax: 1
  config:
    topics: test_strimzi_kafka
    behavior.on.null.values: ignore
    s3.region: ap-southeast-1
    s3.bucket.name: my-bucket-for-test
    flush.size: 1
    consumer.request.timeout.ms: 30000
    errors.retry.delay.max.ms: 30000
    storage.class: io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector
    format.class: io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat
    key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    key.converter.schemas.enable: false
    value.converter.schemas.enable: false
    errors.log.enable: true
    errors.tolerance: all
    errors.retry.timeout: 600000
    errors.log.include.messages: false
    s3.part.size: 5242880
    schema.compatibility: NONE
    consumer.fetch.max.bytes: 1000000
    consumer.fetch.max.wait.ms: 500
```

I tried to downgrade version of Kafka, and S3 Sink Connect but I still got this problem, by the way those plugins works well on the MSK Connect Cluster I just grab it and want to use with Strimzi Kafka Connect.

Comment: Have you created the Dockerfile correctly? All JARs belonging to the same connector should be part of the same subdirectory in `/opt/kafka/plugins/`. Yours are not.

Comment: I think it not about missing class, but it missing method in class, because all library that related with Confluent S3 Sink Connector is already in their subfolder, since I have built everything together but there're still error like this one.

Comment: If it would be missing a method, it would mean your JAR is wrong or somehow broken. But these error messages are very misleading in Java. From my experience, it often is missing something completely different then what it seems to complain anout. So I think you should give my suggestion at least a try ;-).

Comment: I suggest using confluent-hub install, not copying JAR files around. That way, all needed dependencies are pulled as well